# How to use NSString as key in Objective-C++ std::map

Tags: stl, objective-c++

I'm starting work on an Objective-C++ project, getting a feel for how the synthesis of the two languages feels before I do any heavy-duty design.  I am very intrigued by how Automated Reference Counting has been integrated with C++:  we get the equivalent of smart pointers for `NSObjects` that handle retain/release properly in STL containers (cf. David Chisnall's article at http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1745876&seqNum=3).

I want to use STL map as a typesafe mapping from `NSStrings` to C++ values.  I can declare a mapping as

```
std::map<NSString*, MyType> mapping
```

With ARC, this mapping handles the memory management properly.  But it doesn't follow `NSString` value semantics properly, because it's using pointer comparisons instead of `-[NSString compare:]`.

What's the best way to get an STL map to use string comparison instead of pointer comparison?
Should I try to specialize `std::less<NSString*>`?
Should I declare an explicit comparator like `std::map<NSString*, MyType, MyCompare>`?
Should I wrap the `NSString*` keys in a smart pointer that implements `operator<`?

Comment: how do you define best? what is the desired outcome speed memory?

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea objc pointers would work so easily with ARC. Looking at Chisnall's article, you're going to have to add __weak or __strong to your map declaration in order for that to work. Otherwise they're PODs and it won't work. (I don't have an answer to the comparator issue since I do it rarely and forget afterwords. I'd try it in the order you gave.)

Comment: I think if the pointers are strong you don't have to mark them, only if they're weak. Anyway, I'd go with an explicit comparator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'd want a custom comparison object that calls NSString's compare function, something like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>

struct CompareNSString: public std::binary_function<NSString*, NSString*, bool> {
    bool operator()(NSString* lhs, NSString* rhs) const {
        if (rhs != nil)
            return (lhs == nil) || ([lhs compare: rhs] == NSOrderedAscending);
        else
            return false;
    }
};

std::map<NSString*, MyType, CompareNSString> mapping;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  The mapping works well with the comparison object.  I changed the condition to use a consistent ordering for nils (they sort first, before empty strings).

Answer (score 0):

pointer comparisons of unmanaged `NSString` instances are fine, if they are all `NSString` literals. iow, this would work in MRC under those conditions, provided of course there are no duplicate string values, and value is what is being compared.

if not, see Ross'  generally more useful answer (+1).